# Letting front-end user set time zone

Tags: timezone

Following the example in the documentation, this code:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="fields[startDate][datetime]" value="{{ currentValue }}">

<select name="fields[startDate][timezone]">
    <option value="UTC" selected>UTC</option>
    <option value="America/Los_Angeles">Pacific Time</option>
    <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

Does not work for me. Nothing is saved. The form is otherwise working.

**If I simplify to this, it saves: (note that I've removed [datetime] as well as the timezone)**

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="fields[startDate]" value="{{ currentValue }}">
```

**This also does not save:**

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="fields[startDate][datetime]" value="{{ currentValue }}">
```

**If I include a hidden field for timezone, it saves:**

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="fields[startDate][datetime]" value="{{currentValue}}">
{{ hiddenInput('fields[startDate][timezone]', tz) }}
```

Comment: Where is this being posted - to an entry? Looks like you're using [this](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/time-fields.html#working-with-time-field-data) example?

Comment: Is the `startDate` field set to **Show date and time** and has the option **Show Time Zone** active? Otherwise, the timezone is ignored. Also, how are you checking if the timezone is saved or not? What is your expected result in your example and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Yes, the field is set with the "show date and time" and "show time zone options." I'm checking the data, including the timezone, in the control panel. When I am saying it does not save, I mean that the field is empty after saving-- both the date/time and the timezone.

Comment: @RitterKnight No, I'm using [this](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/date-time-fields.html#customizing-the-timezone) example from the DATE field. It is being saved to an entry.

Comment: Voting to close this because it was a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Presumably this was a bug. An update just hit for Craft CMS 3.7.9 which states in the release notes "Fixed a bug where Date fields weren’t handling array values with datetime keys properly. (#9708)".

Code now works as expected.